# Modifying OpenSSH default Windows prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, openssh, prompt

I've just installed OpenSSH on Windows OS based on the following guide.
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

This is the standard prompt

**Windows prompt**

```
userName@mydomain.net@ServerName c:\Users\userName>  

userName@mydomain.net@ServerName c:\Users\userName>
```

**Linux prompt**

```
[root@ServerName ~]# 
[root@ServerName ~]#
```

In Linux, we can easily change this setting by modifying `PS1` variable.

```
[root@ServerName ~]# echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
[root@ServerName ~]#
```

What about Windows? Default prompt for Windows is too long as I'm using domain user. I would like to simplify it.

Answer (score 2):

It's because, the Win32-OpenSSH server sets [`PROMPT` environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html) to

```
<ssh-username>@%COMPUTERNAME% $P$G
```

It's [hard-coded](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable/blob/v7.9.0.0/contrib/win32/win32compat/w32-doexec.c#L185-L196) and not configurable.

---

Though you can revert that by specifying a custom remote command to be like:

```
set PROMPT=$P$G & cmd.exe
```

For example in PuTTY, you can do that by going to *Connection > SSH > Remote Command*.

Comment: still not configurable?

Comment: @ilw No change. I've updated the link to the code of the latest version (v7.9.0.0p1-Beta)

Comment: shame to Microsoft